# Can't figure out how to add fullscreen background video from youtube to this HTML5 Code

Tags: html, video

Here is the code for a website intro. Currently uses a fullscreen 
image, but having trouble figuring out how to add a fullscreen video. The site used is hosted on photofolio if that helps at all.

I would prefer a youtube video autolooping in the background. I've tried adding video to the code, but it never fills the fullscreen.

```
    <style>
#introWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
}
.introSlide {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.65s;
}
#introOptions {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-160px 0 0 -150px;
    text-align:center;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
#introOptions h1 {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:64px;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#introOptions em {
    font-family:'Georgia', serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#BBBBBB;
}
#introOptions button {
    padding:15px 30px;
    margin:40px;
    color:#2fa0d8;
    border:3px solid #2fa0d8;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:400;    
    outline: none;
    transition:all 0.65s;
}
#introOptions button:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    border:3px solid #2fa0d8;
    background-color:#2fa0d8;
}
#introSocial {
    cursor:default;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:60px;
    color:#2fa0d8;
    text-align:center;
}
#introSocial a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#introSocial svg {
    fill:#2fa0d8;
    transition:fill 0.65s;
}
#introSocial svg:hover {
    fill:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<div id='introWrapper'>
<img class='introSlide' src='https://33acda504924667afc4c-95ab99cbba1f87315d458f4e201677b2.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/media/intro-image-sample.jpg' onload='var introImg = this; function scale(i) { var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight, ir = i.width/i.height; if ((w/h) < ir) { w = Math.round(h*ir); i.style.width = w + "px"; i.style.height = h + "px"; } else { h = Math.round(w/ir); i.style.width = w + "px"; i.style.height = h + "px"; } i.style.left = ((window.innerWidth - i.width) * 0.5) + "px"; i.style.top = ((window.innerHeight - i.height) * 0.5) + "px"; } window.onresize = function() { scale(introImg); }; scale(this); this.style.opacity = 0.5;'/>
<div id='introOptions'>
    <h1>Design X</h1>
    <em><i>Websites for Professionals</i></em>
    <button id='introEnterBtn' onclick='javascript:dx.site.events.dispatchEvent("introFadeOut")'>Enter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to add a video to the background of this webpage rather than an image. Sorry for not being clear